# Better clean functional code or large chunk of code

Tags: sql, database, performance, function, c#-4.0

In this question i am going to ask about basic practices. Today i faced situation in which i need to update database table value with this code .

```
   public void updateUsrProfileName(string usrId, string name)
     {
         query = "update [db_user].[dbo].[usr_profiles] set [Name]=@name where [usrid]=@usrid ";
         try
         {
             com = new SqlCommand(query,con);
             com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name);
             com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrid",usrId);
             con.Open();
             com.ExecuteNonQuery();
             con.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             con.Close();
             throw e;
         }
     }
```

I need to repeat above function for every column of table, So i come up with one common function to reduce code

```
  public void Commonfunction(SqlCommand com, string var)
     {
         try
         {
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrid", var);
            con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             con.Close();
             throw e;
         }
     }
```

and call above function like this

```
     public void updateUsrProfileName(string usrId, string name)
     {
         query = "update [db_user].[dbo].[usr_profiles] set [Name]=@name where [usrid]=@usrid ";
         try
         {
             com = new SqlCommand(query,con);
             com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name);
             Commonfunction(SqlCommand com, string name);
         }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 con.Close();
                 throw e;
             }
         }
```

Advantage:-
Clean code no redundancy.
Less code length which is very less in difference

Disadvantage:-
As the no of function calls increases performance decreases as it need to match arguments, map function calls etc

In this situation where very lesser code is redundant is it good to move with common function and in which conditions we should think about divide in function or not.

Comment: Update the entire record. Write just one `updateUserProfile(UserProfile profile)` function.

Comment: I think that will b wastage of resources, as if only need to update name why should i move up with entire row it will affect performance

Comment: how many times are you updating a user profile per second? Not once, I would guess.

Comment: Above one is just an example of scenario. Update request can be sent many times within a second.

Answer (score 0):

Always "move it" (to a shared method rather than repeating code). until the unlikely event the profiling shows you have a problem in that area.

Comment: What performance issue? Have you measured it to claim there exists some performance issue at all? How big is your data? How many updates/s? I would start making the code as simple as possible, measure performance and then tweak if it is really necessary. Otherwise you end up with duplicated code for no reason at all.

Comment: Duplicating your code instead of writing it properly the first time is almost never the solution to a performance problem...

Comment: I didn't measure it but i read somewhere that function calls charge some time and i support duplicating code is not good approach. But i was not sure what to do when duplicate code is not much.

Comment: The overhead of a function call is trivial in comparison to the benefits of maintainable code (as soon as you duplicate something you are guaranteed that there is a bug and you'll only fix it in one place...) Write good code and don't concern yourself (too much) with optimization until you know you have a problem.

Comment: Function calls are not going to be your main problem, they take nanoseconds to microseconds. RDBMS roundtrip will usually take on the order of several milliseconds. You should go for the simplest solution with the less code possible that makes it work. Once you hit trouble, profile. You could also improve database performance by using a stored procedure to update the entire record at once and move part of your logic to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to put some general logic in a separate method. I have simplified your code by removing excessive try/catch block and added `finally` clause.

```
public void Commonfunction(SqlCommand com, string var)
{
    try
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usrid", var);
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con != null)
        {
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

public void updateUsrProfileName(string usrId, string name)
{
    query = "update [db_user].[dbo].[usr_profiles] set [Name]=@name where [usrid]=@usrid ";

    com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    Commonfunction(com, name);
}
```

Comment: kirill i have doubt if i remove try catch from  updateUsrProfileName(string usrId, string name) will it throw the exception to business logic caller.

Comment: Exceptions will propagate up the call stack if you don't catch them.